# Full Width Dialog on Bottom of Screen - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have to create the similar UX on some event. This is the UX of Any.Do android app.

I tried to achieve this by specifying my activity theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` and setting Window Layout Params gravity to Bottom.

But I am getting this :

[image]

The Dialog is not drawing of full width. I tried to alter following properties of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` :

```
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
```

Then I get this :

[image]

When I increase any of Minor or Major width properties, The Dialog appears as following:

[image]

My Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ScreenRateReminder"
          android:theme="@style/CustomDialog"/>
```

Style Definition:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```

Layout Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/company_info_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/building_image"/>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tagline"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_satisfied"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_smile" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_happy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_average"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/angry_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_angry"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Code:

```
public class RateReminderActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =  window.getAttributes();
        layoutParams .gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        window.setAttributes(layoutParams);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen_rate_reminder);

}
```

I even tried by : window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

and :

```
wlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
wlp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

But for me nothing is making the dialog as full width.

Comment: Add your XML layout.

Comment: Layout Added @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: I guess it would be better if you use BottomSheet

Comment: @NabinKhatiwada I did it through BottomSheetDialog and it gave the same experience. If any one has to use this as a stand alone dialog (as my case) then 'Draw over other apps' has to be enabled through device settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme, it will give transparent Activity,

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And Activity with just setContentView

```
public class RateReminderActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen_rate_reminder);

}
```

And your layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/company_info_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/building_image"/>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tagline"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_satisfied"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_smile"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_happy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_average"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/angry_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_angry"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edited:**

If you want to work with `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat` you can use style like this,

```
<style name="AppThemeTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is the problem in that..?

Comment: After pressing recent apps button, when user taps back on the same app, the dialog was visible along with the recent apps (due to transparent background of activity).

Comment: So you don't want anything in the background while open this..?

Comment: See, the UX was OK up till the event upon which we triggered this Dialog, but the bug arouse if we press recent apps button when Dialog is visible. Any how, I achieved the required functionality through BottomSheetDialog. However your answer enabled me to think in a different dimension. ty